# How do I start using Enterprise Library?

Tags: enterprise-library

Please help me start using Enterprise Library for the first time. I am completely new to it but have used ADO.NET so far.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the [Developer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953191%28PandP.50%29.aspx) and progress onto the [Hands-on Labs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6932).
Pick the application blocks and topics of interest.